# Determine $[f + g]_B$ and $[f \circ g]_{B'}$ using the change of bases matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

In the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider the bases:
$$B = (v_1, v_2) = ((1, 2), (1, 3))$$
$$B' = (v_1', v_2') = ((1, 0), (2, 1))$$

Let $f, g$ be endomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ having the matrices:
$$[f]_B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$[g]_{B'} = \begin{pmatrix}
-7 & -13\\ 
5 & 7
\end{pmatrix}$$

Determine $[f + g]_B$ and $[f \circ g]_{B'}$ using the change of bases matrices.

I found the change of bases matrices:
$$T_{BB'} = \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & -5\\ 
2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$T_{B'B} = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 5\\ 
-2 & -3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, I used the known formula for finding $[g]_{B}$:
$$[g]_B = T_{B'B}[g]_{B'}T_{BB'} = \begin{pmatrix}
-20 & -32\\ 
13 & 20
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, this result is wrong because it differs from the result I got by without using the change of basis matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-26 & -46\\ 
19 & 33
\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you, please, help me figure out what I did wrong and how I should do it properly? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What calculation did you do without change of basis matrices?

Comment: The matrices $T$ in your calculation of [g]_B are in wrong order

Comment: @MichaelBurr I expressed $g(v_1')$ and $g(v_2')$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$